# How to post data from a ping response in xml into MySql using PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing, http-post, ping

I'm sending live contacts from a form to a third party. If the contact meets the third party criteria they sent me a response (XML) with an id number. I need to add that id number to a full information form and send back to third party. I'm not sure how to parse XML data with PHP. I will post the response in MySql also and make a post out.

Here is the form code sample:

```
<form name="ping_test" id="ping_test" action="http://mypost.com/post.asmx/pingAddrLocator" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="PgmCD" value="xxx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ProviderID" value="xxx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Year" value="xxx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Make" value="xxx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Model" value="xxx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Trim" value="XLX" />
    <input type="text" name="Zip" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['Zip']) ? htmlentities($_REQUEST['Zip']) : ''); ?>" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit()">Apply Now!</a>

</form>
```

I change the fields and add xxx values for testing only...
This is the response xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>
<DealerList numDealers="1">
<Dealer>
<Id>185166</Id>
<Name>XXX</Name>
<Address>XXX</Address>
<City>XXX</City>
<State>XX</State>
<PostalCode>77777</PostalCode>
<Country>USA</Country>
<Contact>
<Name>John D</Name>
<Email>internet@mypost.com</Email>
<Phone></Phone>
</Contact>
<Distance>3.85</Distance>
</Dealer>
</DealerList>
```

Comment: simplexml_load_string

Comment: try that before with no results. Let me try again. Thank you!!

Comment: If that doesn't work, just google "parse XML with PHP", I'm sure there are tons of results. Let alone on stack overflow.

Comment: I been searching on this for almost two days with no lucky at all. That's why I ask here!!

Comment: I'm a little unclear. At this point, are you still trying to capture that XML into a string, or do you have it assigned to a variable and now need to parse it?

Comment: I'm trying to capture the XML data and then assign variables. Eg. the <id>= $acceptCode; if the num of dealers <=2 I need assign <dealer>=$dlr1 and so on.